# getting "OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname does not match the server certificate)" in rails 4 using sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, production, sendgrid

i am getting "OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname does not match the server certificate)" in rails 4 production mode using sendgrid

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => 'xxxx',
    :password => 'xxxx',
    :domain => 'moorem.com',
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

the following error getting
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname does not match the server certificate):
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:26:in `contact_create'
```

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is for `*.smtp.sendgrid.net` in the common name and both `*.smtp.sendgrid.net` and `smtp.sendgrid.net` in the subject alternative names (SAN) section. If one compares only against the common name it would not match, but against SAN it should.

So I guess this is a bug. I don't know which ruby version you are using, but in the recent version the hostname verification looks mostly fine too me (only too permissive regarding wildcards) so I would recommend to check with a newer ruby version.